# plsql check at least one variable is not null inside where clause

Tags: oracle, plsql, where-clause

I'd like to filter columns, depending on two variables, namely (in pseudo code):

- **A** if columns 1 and 2 are not null, then filter on both filter1 and filter2, otherwise
- **B** if column 1 is not null, then do filter on filter1, otherwise
- **C** if column 2 is not null, then do filter on filter2

I have tried the following PL/SQL statement:

```
select * from table t where 
((t.column1 is not null and t.column1=filter1 and t.column2 is not null and t.column2=t.filter2) -- condition A
 or (t.column1 is not null and t.column1=filter1) -- condition B
 or (t.column2 is not null and t.column2=filter2)); -- condition C
```

Although I have checked that it works for each condition independently, it does not work on all three conditions. 
E.g.:

- if there is only condition A, that works,
- or it there are only conditions B and C, that works.
- But that doesn't for condition A, B and C altogether.

What is wrong ? Please help :)

Comment: The solution proposed by @JoseRuiSantos works, although I still don't know why my first (somehow too complicated) attempt does not! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think the other way around, when they are null:

```
select *
  from table t
 where (t.column1 is null or t.column1=filter1)
       and
       (t.column2 is null or t.column2=filter2);
```

Consider this condition:

```
(t.column1 is null or t.column1=filter1)
```

If `t.column1 is null` is true, then the `t.column1=filter1` is not even evaluated, since `true or whatever` is always `true`. Which means, that `t.column1=filter1` is evaluated only when `t.column1` is not null.

---

Let's test each situation.

**column1 = null, column2 = null**
The query returns all rows, since the condition is
`where (true or t.column1=filter1) and (true or t.column2=filter2)` which simplifies to
`where true and true`

**column1 = null, column2 != null**
The condition is `where (true) and (false or t.column2=filter2)` which simplifies to
`where t.column2=filter2`

**column1 != null, column2 = null**
The condition is `where (false or t.column1=filter1) and (true)` which simplifies to
`where t.column1=filter1`

**column1 != null, column2 != null**
The condition is `where (false or t.column1=filter1) and (false or t.column2=filter2)` which simplifies to
`where t.column1=filter1 and t.column2=filter2`

Comment: Thank you, it works :) I understand your explanation, although I still don't see why my initial conditions do not work. If I use your test on them, this should validate as well?

Comment: It should also validate, but keep it simple. The way I did is more intuitive in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select *
  from table t
 where ((t.column1 = filter1 and t.column2 = t.filter2) -- condition 1
       or (t.column1 = filter1 and t.column2 is null )  -- condition 2
       or (t.column2 = filter2 and t.column1 is null)); -- condition 3
```

filters value should not be null, otherwise you have to use nvl as like the following:

```
select *
  from table t
 where ((t.column1 = nvl(filter1,-1) and t.column2 = nvl(t.filter2, -1) ) -- condition 1
       or (t.column1 = nvl(filter1,-1) and t.column2 is null )            -- condition 2
       or (t.column2 = nvl(filter2,-1) and t.column1 is null));           -- condition 3
```

Comment: replace -1 with any other value you want like nvl(filter1, 'null value')

Comment: Sorry, I removed my previous comment because I realized wasn't a problem, as you pointed out.